# Racket. Fill the table with data from database

Tags: sql, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I'm trying to fill the table in my GUI with data from database.

 Here's the database example:

```
Team
---------------------------------------------------------
|    id    |     name      |    city     |     coach    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    1     | Atlanta Hawks |   Atlanta   | Lloyd Pierce |
|    2     | Boston Celtics|   Boston    | Brad Stevens |
|    3     | Chicago Bulls |   Chicago   |  Jim Boylen  |
|    4     | Brooklyn Nets |   New-York  | Jacque Vaughn|

Tournament
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    id    |     name      |    city     |     prise    |     year    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |    FirstCup   |   Atlanta   |     100000   |     2018    |
|    2     |    SecondCup  |   Boston    |     200000   |     2019    |
|    3     |    ThirdCup   |   Chicago   |     300000   |     2017    |
|    4     |    AnotherCup |   New-York  |     400000   |     2020    |
```

And here's my GUI with some dummy data in tab-panels:

```
#lang racket
(require
  racket/gui/base
  racket/class
  racket/list)

(require db)

(define pgc
  (postgresql-connect #:user "postgres"
                      #:database "bascketball"
                      #:password "root"))

(define Team-Table #f)
(define Tournament-Table #f)
(define Team-Data #f)
(define Tournament-Data #f)

(define Basketball-App #f)
(define Main-Frame #f)
(define Group-Box #f)
(define Horizontal-Pane-Menu #f)
(define Tab-Panel #f)
(define Team-Tab #f)
(define Tournament-Tab #f)

(define (Basketball-App-init
         (Main-Frame-width 800)
         (Main-Frame-height 600))

  (set! Main-Frame
        (new
         frame%
         (parent Basketball-App)
         (label "Basketball App")
         (width Main-Frame-width)
         (height Main-Frame-height)))

  (set! Group-Box
        (new
         group-box-panel%
         (parent Main-Frame)
         (label "")
         (alignment (list 'right 'bottom))))

  (set! Horizontal-Pane-Menu
        (new
         horizontal-pane%
         (parent Group-Box)
         (stretchable-width #f)
         (stretchable-height #f)))

  (set! Tab-Panel
        (new
         (class tab-panel%
           (super-new)
           (define child-panels '())
           (define/public
             (add-child-panel p label)
             (set! child-panels (append child-panels (list p)))
             (send this append label)
             (when (> (length child-panels) 1) (send this delete-child p)))
           (define/public
             (active-child n)
             (send this change-children
                   (lambda (children) (list (list-ref child-panels n))))))
         (parent Group-Box)
         (choices (list))
         (callback (λ (tp e) (send tp active-child (send tp get-selection))))
         (stretchable-width #t)
         (stretchable-height #t)))

  (set! Team-Tab
        (new
         (class vertical-panel%
           (init parent)
           (init-field label)
           (super-new (parent parent))
           (send parent add-child-panel this label))
         (parent Tab-Panel)
         (label "Team")
         (alignment (list 'left 'center))))

  (set! Team-Table (new list-box%
                        [parent Team-Tab]
                        [choices (list )]
                        [label ""]
                        [style (list 'single 'column-headers 'variable-columns)]
                        [columns (list "Id" "Name" "City" "Coach")]))

  #: Dummy data
  (set! Team-Data (list (list "TeamTest" "TeamTest" "TeamTest")
                        (list "TeamTest" "TeamTest" "TeamTest")
                        (list "TeamTest" "TeamTest" "TeamTest")
                        (list "TeamTest" "TeamTest" "TeamTest")))
  (send Team-Table set (list-ref Team-Data 0) (list-ref Team-Data 1) (list-ref Team-Data 2) (list-ref Team-Data 3))

  (set! Tournament-Tab
        (new
         (class vertical-panel%
           (init parent)
           (init-field label)
           (super-new (parent parent))
           (send parent add-child-panel this label))
         (parent Tab-Panel)
         (label "Tournament")
         (alignment (list 'left 'center))))

  (set! Tournament-Table (new list-box%
                        [parent Tournament-Tab]
                        [choices (list )]
                        [label ""]
                        [style (list 'single 'column-headers 'variable-columns)]
                        [columns (list "Id" "Name" "City" "Prise" "Year")]))
  #: Dummy data
    (set! Tournament-Data (list (list "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest")
                              (list "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest")
                              (list "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest")
                              (list "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest")
                              (list "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest" "TournamentTest")))
  (send Tournament-Table set (list-ref Tournament-Data 0) (list-ref Tournament-Data 1) (list-ref Tournament-Data 2) (list-ref Tournament-Data 3) (list-ref Tournament-Data 4))

      (send Main-Frame show #t))
    (module+ main (Basketball-App-init))
```

So I want to load data from database when I'm switch to tab and fill the table with loaded data.

I have two problems with this:

First - How should I know when user switch the tab and what tab is it (in other words, where should I put my SQL query to use it only when the tab switches).

Second - When I'm using some kind of this queries:

```
(query-rows pgc "select * from team")
```

I get just a string and I have no idea how to put this string to my table. I have to split this string and put every element as a cell of a table.

So, what's your advice in this project?
[image]

Comment: Given the example `team` table above, `(query-rows pgc "select * from team")` should return a list of vectors, where each vector has 4 elements. Are you sure it's returning a string?

Comment: @RyanCulpepper I'm trying this one `(define data (query-rows pgc "select * from team"))
                     (send Team-Table set (list-ref data 0) (list-ref data 1) (list-ref data 2) (list-ref data 3))` and get this `set in list-box%: contract violation
  expected: (listof label-string?)
  given: '#(1 "Atlanta Hawks" "Atlanta" "Lloyd Pierce")`

Comment: Yes, `'#(1 "Atlanta Hawks" "Atlanta" "Lloyd Pierce")` is a vector. You can convert it to a list using `vector->list`, you can get individual elements using `vector-ref`, and so on.

Comment: @RyanCulpepper ok, I've transformed vector to list using `vector->list` but I still get this error `set in list-box%: contract violation
  expected: (listof label-string?)
  given: '(1 "Atlanta Hawks" "Atlanta" "Lloyd Pierce")` Maybe it's a problem of elements because they are strings probably, but program expect label-string ?

Comment: No, `1` isn't a string, it's a number. `"1"` is a string, and you can use `number->string` to convert `1` to `"1"`. But I recommend that you stop and read the first few chapters of the Racket Guide (https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html) first.